# Finding AES ciphertext stealing test vectors?

Tags: encryption

I am unable to find any test vector document for AES CTS (ciphertext stealing).

Can you help me to find some by pointing me into the right direction or at an according reference? Do they exist at all?

Comment: Note that Ciphertext Stealing can be used along with different mode of operation. But its biggest interest is when used with CBC, since the ECB mode is to be avoided at all costs and CTR mode (and similar) can simply use truncated outputs instead. The answer below is assuming you are using CBC, which I hope you do. You may want to specify which mode of operation you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what exactly you need.

Some test vectors can be found in the document "[RFC 3962 - AES Encryption for Kerberos 5](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3962.txt)". If you take a look at page 11, you'll find some test vectors for CBC with ciphertext stealing, using an initial vector of all-zero.

Also, there are test vectors to be found at more exotic places like [mozilla.org test vectors for AES CTS](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/security/nss/cmd/bltest/tests/aes_cts/aes-cts-type-1-vectors.txt). They took the original test vectors for AES CTS-3 (Kerberos) and modified them for AES CTS-1 (NIST).

I'm sure that you favorite search engine will help you pinpoint the rest.